# Is it a good practice to use Nothing in generics?

Tags: kotlin

Like in this example:

```
sealed class Option<T>

object None : Option<Nothing>() // <-- like this

class Some<T> : Option<T>()
```

Or, if it's not a good practice, what should I use here instead?

Are there any official response/article on that? Or is there any argumentation that this is a good practice?

I know that `Nothing` was designed to be used as a type for return value for functions that never returns any value, so I'm not sure if using it as a generic parameter is a valid use.

I know there is an [article](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlins-nothing-its-usefulness-in-generics-5076a6a457f7) that says that you can do that, but I'm not sure if I can trust it.

And the author of [koptional](https://github.com/gojuno/koptional/blob/master/koptional/src/main/kotlin/com/gojuno/koptional/Optional.kt) uses it too, but I don't know if I can trust that either.

Also, it looks like in Scala `Option` is implemented similar to that, `None` have type `Option[Nothing]` and Scala's `Nothing` is similar to Kotlin's `Nothing`.

Comment: I don't know how this would be worth an answer, but yes, this is the perfect place to use `Nothing`!

Comment: I use java.lang.Void as a return in this case

Comment: @zsmb13 Are there any chance that you have a link to someone close to language designers or maybe other trusted person recommending that? Or maybe some argumentation for why it's a good practice?  Because I know that Nothing was designed to be used as a type for return value for functions that never returns any value, so I'm not sure if using it as a generic parameter is a valid use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with [@zsmb13's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049656/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-nothing-in-generics#comment92999093_53049656). Using `Nothing` in a generic type hierarchy is perfectly valid and even gives benefits over other options:

- First, [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) is embedded in the Kotlin type system as a subtype of any other type, so it plays well with [generics variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html). For example, `Option<Nothing>` can be passed where `Option<out Foo>` is expected.
- Second, the compiler will perform control flow checks and detect unreachable code after a `Nothing`-returning member call when the type is statically known.

See also: [A Whirlwind Tour of the Kotlin Type Hierarchy](http://natpryce.com/articles/000818.html)

Comment: There, look! This guy is from JetBrains :P

Comment: unfortunately, `Nothing` generics still not supported when testing (mocking): https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/158

Comment: Well that's only one mocking library (and even there they says it's fixed)